# Sql error when casting char column to varchar value

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a char(1) column but I want select this column like this:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN [ENABLED] = 'Y' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS EnabledTitle)
FROM [ICS_USERS]
```

I am getting this error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Yes' to data type bit.

Is there any way to show varchar values in char columns?
Thanks

Comment: could you please provide your table structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call `CAST()`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [ENABLED] = 'Y' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS EnabledTitle
FROM   [ICS_USERS]
```

`CAST` converts a value. Your conversion takes place on the `CASE` statement.